# Is yin and yang haram

Tags: halal-haram, sin

Assalamualaikum, i actually heard this topic and i have a question whether yin and yang which some people say is like equality between 2 things, so is all this philosophy haram?

Comment: Do you mean believing in that philosophy?

Comment: What’s the point in believing in this ? Just stick with what Allah sent down, that’s enough.